# Cannot connect to X server using docker on OSX

Tags: macos, paraview, docker-toolbox, xquartz, openfoam

I am trying to install openFoam on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (http://www.openfoam.com/download/install-binary.php) by using Docker-toolbox. 
I can do without problems all the suggested steps, but then, when I try to run the example included in the installation guide, I cannot open paraFoam, since it returns the following error:

> `paraview: cannot connect to X server`

I have also installed XQuartz but it doesn't seem to help much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you [get the latest paraview](http://www.paraview.org/download/) from Kitware. It has a native OpenFOAM reader built-in, which I always use. The only thing you have to do, instead of calling

```
paraFoam
```

is to create an empty file with a `foam` extension. Like so:

```
touch foo.foam
```

Then you can run start paraview like any other mac application, browse to to the respective case-directory and "open" the empty `foo.foam` file:

```
paraview foo.foam
```

If you would like to use a command similar to `paraFoam` or `paraview` in the command line, then use your command line to change into the `Paraview.app` and find `paraview`, which is the actual executable. Create a symbolic link pointing to that executable. I do the same, since I like to use the latest `paraview` instead of the one provided with OpenFOAM.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I tried to do what you suggested, but when I try to open the empty file on the terminal it tells me either command not found or cannot connect to X server again. 
About the last lines you wrote, could you please explain it again? I'm sorry, I'm not very practical with all these stuff!

Comment: Have you tried to do execute the downloaded `Paraview.app` and open the `foo.foam` file, that you have created using the `touch` command?

Comment: Ah ok sorry, now I got it, and it actually works! One last question if you don't mind: so, if I understood correctly, every time I'm working with openFoam I can create the file from the terminal and then open it directly from the folder with Paraview, but touch creates an empty file, is then this file automatically modified when I do the blockMesh? Thank you again

Comment: This file is only used to "trick" paraview into opening an OpenFOAM case, which is a directory and not a single file. Paraview itself cannot open a directory and needs a file. For this purpose the empty `<something>.foam` file is created. This file stays empty and is not touched. `blockMesh` does not touch it, it only changes the contents of `constant/polyMesh`. Welcome to Stackoverflow btw ;).

Comment: Well, I can open parafoam now as you told me, but I'm now trying to understand how to use it when programming, so how to make it show the geometry I wrote in the blockMeshDict document. It has been a steep learning curve for both terminal stuffs and openFoam itself!

Comment: Well, OpenFOAM in general has a very steep lerning curve. This is due to the lack of of documentation and the complexity of the field. Maybe [OpenFOAM Primer](http://www.sourceflux.de/book) helps, it's a book on OpenFOAM. 
As you are new to Stackoverflow, have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :).

Comment: You have read the user's guide, haven't you? The tutorial on `blockMesh`, that's in there is quite useful, actually. Don't start with the hole in the plate thing, but with something with the cavity.