# how to open paraView in a Docker window

Tags: docker, paraview, openfoam

This is the same problem discussed in
*[Cannot connect to X server using docker on OS X - Part II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497771/cannot-connect-to-x-server-using-docker-on-os-x-part-ii)*
but never resolved.
In MacOS El Capitan, I'm running the OpenFOAM binary under Docker as there is no native version. I want to use paraView to view results. Cannot run the paraView supplied inside OpenFOAM since I get
**paraview: cannot connect to X server**
The advice here
*[Cannot connect to X server using docker on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021958/cannot-connect-to-x-server-using-docker-on-osx)*
is to install paraView separately and run it from a normal terminal. This did not work as a normal terminal cannot "see" Docker files. And I cannot run the suggested
**open -a paraview foam.foam**
inside the docker terminal, as for some reason it does not recognize the "open" command.

Perhaps some Docker expert can help?

Answer (score 1):

The team at OpenFOAM.org worked a lot on the issue recently to release a good solution to the MacOS users (http://openfoam.org/download/4-1-macos/). 
Unfortunately, they reached the conclusion that going through X in Docker although working was not a solution because it freezes most of the time and it is really not convenient. 
I understand from the question that the files cannot be seen from the MacOS terminal (that would require to know which version has been used). In the release of OpenFOAM 4.1 (see link above) in Docker this is done by the script and therefore it is directly possible to access the file by opening them with ParaView in a regular terminal.